# Automatic naming of checkboxes

Tags: hyperref, forms

I am using the below code to make 2 interactive checkboxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\CheckBox{c}

\CheckBox{c}

\end{document}
```

[image: checkbox multiple latex]

But if I tick one of them, the other one gets ticked as well. I know I can name them differently using `\CheckBox[name=xx]{}` But I would like to know if there is an automated way to name these instead of doing it manually every time I need to add another checkbox. When I need to exit my document to use many checkboxes I end up using weird names like `\CheckBox[name=C10.1.1.2.1]{}`.

I also accept answers that give me alternative ways to create checkboxes, as long as the checkbox option can be saved on the document and is visible when ticked.

Comment: I would also like a "checkbox" tag for tex.stackexchange.com/, I think it would be nice!

Comment: The proper tag for such things is probablly `forms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own macro that uses a counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{checkboxcount}
\newcommand{\AutonameCheckBox}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{checkboxcount}%
    \CheckBox[name={checkbox\thecheckboxcount}]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\AutonameCheckBox{c}

\AutonameCheckBox{c}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

This results in a checkbox that automatically gets a name such as `checkboxX` where `X` is a number that counts up for every checkbox.

[image]

I am unsure what you mean with that the "option can be saved" or "is visible when ticket", though. Maybe you can add some more information about how you exactly would like to use these checkboxes.